# How to build Arrays, push to them, and loop through them in Java/ Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I come from an action script back ground and i am baffled by how to use arrays in java.

In my main activity i created an empty array called mIcons like so

```
private Array mIcons;
```

Now i want to set the value of that array by using a method from my DataBaseHelper class which looks like this:

```
public Array getHomeScreenIcons() {

        Array iconList;

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + homeIcons;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
```

***iconList.push(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));***

```
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "List Created"); 
        // return contact list

}
```

that bold line jumping out of the code is the problem so far.. how do i PUSH to my array

Then later i will want to run a for loop for the array from my main activity using.length

Comment: The best way to learn about the primitive language constructs is through a book or an online tutorial.  This question involves such elementary syntax that it doesn't really belong on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an **ArrayList** paramaterized to any type you want

`ArrayList<Integer> iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

add with

`iconList.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));`

**Iterate with**

```
for (int i: iconList)
{
    // i is your entire array starting at index 0
}
```

**or**

```
for (int i=0; i< iconList.size(), i++)
{

}
```

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, except that you cannot pass primitives as the type of a Collection.  You will need `ArrayList<Integer> iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>()` instead.

Comment: Wow, ok guys, first off thank you, secondly, can you explain to me the difference between Array and ArrayList?  I was looking it up and apparently an Array has to have a predefined length?  Obviously ArrayList is what i want to use, but if someone could explain to me why Array's have to have predefined lengths i would love you.. seems absolutely retarded to me?

Comment: @erik They are very similar, see this link: http://max.cs.kzoo.edu/AP/Workshops/Java/ArraysArrayLists.html . Remember, you cannot use primitives in an `ArrayList` you have to use type `Object`

Comment: @erik Just think if you need a fixed number of primitives, lets say 10 integers, it will be less resource-intensive to use an `Array` with `int` than it would be to use an `ArrayList` with the `Integer` object

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking about ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> iconList = ArrayList<String>();
iconList.add("Stuff");
```

and then later to loop through

```
for (int i=0; i<iconList.size(); i++) {
    String newStuff = iconList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably hit up some basic java tutorials to get used to the array syntax and functionality. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html could be a good starting point.

Looking at your specific problem -

You generally don't want to use the Array class in the manner that you do. It's more of a helper class. Also, it seems that you are going for stack semantics, and you'd likely want to use a Stack instead.

First, arrays:
you declare an array like so:

```
Type[] myArray = new Type[arraySize];
```

and then you access it with index like so:

```
Type myThingFromArray = myArray[myArrayIndex];
```

and you put things in it like so:

```
myArray[myTargetIndex] = myObjectOfTypeType;
```

Raw arrays in java have static size and are not easily growable. For most applications it would be a better idea to use a member of the Collections framework instead. If you're actively looking for a stack (as you mention pushing) then you could use `Stack<Integer>` and have all the regular stack operations.

Another benefit of using a modern collection class is that you can iterate through your collection using the for-each construct, which eliminates some regular for boilerplate. An example:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> iconList;
public Array getHomeScreenIcons() {

    Array iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + homeIcons;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            iconList.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "List Created"); 
    // return contact list

    //Iterate like so:
    for (Integer i : iconList){ 
        System.out.println("Here's all integers in the icon-list: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define arrays in Java like this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[3]; // array for three ints
String[] stringArray = new String[10]; // array for 10 Strings
```

So for your code, you can do something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int[] iconList = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    int index = 0;
    do {
        iconList[index] = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        index++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

After that you can loop over the array like this:

```
for (int icon : iconList) {
    // Do something with icon
}
```